# Como defino ordenação personalizada no retorno de um DB?

Tags: php, mysql

Hoje eu tenho um catalogo de produtos (imagens) simples que mostra todos os produtos juntos ou por categorias.

Porém, quando mostrar todos juntos só sei ordenar por ASC ou DESC, mas preciso ordenar diferente. Quando mostrar todos quero que apareça um produto X primeiro ou **na posição que eu definir**, e não uma simples ASC ou DESC, pois quando adiciono um Y, ou ele aparece no inicio (ordenando id by DESC) ou no final (ordenando id by ASC).

Gostaria de implementar no meu código (PHP+MySQL). Vi um exemplo aqui: http://mateusgamba.xpg.uol.com.br/ordenar_tabela.html (no caso o administrador irá escolher onde aparece o produto, que pode subir ou descer).

Caso o post esteja meio confuso estou a disposição para explicar melhor.

Comment: se voce nao quer em ordem crecsente ou decrecsente em qual ordem seria essa que voce gostaria? voce pode usar uma cararacteristica do produto x para definir uma ordem tipo cor tamanho visibilidade da imagem

Comment: Para esses casos, eu adiciono uma coluna chamada ranking, no mesmo sentido que o colega @miguel escreveu e mando ordenar por essa coluna.

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso tem de armazenar a ordem costumizada que quer. Pode criar uma coluna na sua tabela com a ordem (int), e depois ordenar a partir daí com o `SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY ordem ASC/DESC ...`, tal como faz com o id. Ou seja, quando insere/edita o produto passa a inserir mais um dado, que é em que lugar (1 para o primeiro, 2 para o segundo, 3 para o terceiro ...) em que quer que ele fique.

Atenção que com isto, se não quiser que hajam produtos com lugares (`ordem`) iguais tem de trabalhar a sua lógica para:

**INSERÇÃO**

Portanto se tiver um produto com o lugar 5 (`ordem` é 5), mas se mais tarde vai inserir outro que acha que deve ficar no lugar 5 vai ter de incrementar `+1` a `ordem` de todos os produtos cujo a ordem é >= 5, (`UPDATE produtos SET ordem = ordem + 1 WHERE ordem >= 5`) e depois insere o novo produto. Neste exemplo o primeiro que estava no lugar 5 vai passar a estar no lugar 6, 6 -> 7, 7 -> 8 etc...

**EDIÇÃO: Subida de lugar (ex: de lugar 7 para lugar 2)**

Aqui o funcionamento vai ser um pouco diferente, caso o produto esteja em  sétimo e queiramos alterar para que fique em segundo fazemos com que todos os produtos cuja `ordem` for entre 2 e 7 alterem o número do lugar em que aparecem. Ou seja, somente os produtos de `ordem < 7` e `ordem >= 2` é que vão ser incrementados em 1 na coluna `ordem`. Fazemos `UPDATE produtos SET ordem = ordem + 1 WHERE ordem >= 2 AND ordem < 7`, e logo a seguir fazemos o update da `ordem` do produto de 7 para 2 (`UPDATE produtos SET ordem = 2 WHERE id = ID_SETIMO_PRODUTO`)

**EDIÇÃO: Descida de lugar (ex: de lugar 2 para lugar 7)**

Aqui, seguindo a lógica oposta à de subida de lugar fazemos com que todos os produtos cuja `ordem > 2` e `ordem <= 7` é que vão ser DECREMENTADOS em 1 na coluna da `ordem`. Fazemos `UPDATE produtos SET ordem = ordem - 1 WHERE ordem > 2 AND ordem <= 7` e logo a seguir a fazer o update da `ordem` do produto para 7 (`UPDATE produtos SET ordem = 7 WHERE id = ID_SEGUNDO_PRODUTO`).

**DELETE**

Aqui temos de decrementar em 1 à `ordem` de todos os produtos cuja `ordem` for superior à ordem do produto que apagamos. Se quisermos apagar o produto que está em sétimo fazemos `UPDATE produtos SET ordem = ordem - 1 WHERE ordem > 7` e depois finalmente apagamos o produto `DELETE FROM produtos WHERE id = ID_SETIMO_PRODUTO`

**Desta meneira garante que estejam sempre consecutivos e enumerados pela ordem que quer sem que hajam produtos com lugares (`ordem`) repetidos**

Comment: Não entendi o problema de ter dois produtos com a mesma ordem. Eu uso ranking em uma série de situações, e deixo "empatados" os produtos de mesma relevância, sem nenhum tipo de problema. Inclusive, como exemplo, a pessoa pode fazer um `ORDER BY ordem, nome`, assim você tem o ranking e ordem alfabética no caso de empates.

Comment: É claro que há casos em que não há diferença e para si funciona assim. Mas entre dois produtos ranking 5, pode crer um antes do outro, desta maneira evitava-se isso

Comment: Entendo. Só perguntei pra ver se tinha algum detalhe que eu deixei passar despercebido, grato pelo retorno.

Comment: :) . Há alguma forma de tornar a resposta mais clara? Até acho que me expliquei bem

Comment: Acho que o caminho é esse mesmo, acho que se quiser incrementar, pode por uma tabelinha exemplo, ou um SQL Fiddle demonstrando, mas talvez seja exagero. Melhor esperar o Autor se manifestar pra ver se ele entendeu :)